# How to sort firebase data by date in android

Tags: android, firebase

I searched almost in web for the solution but got correct solution.
i need to sort list of data by date which they added. i added a **TIMESTAMP** but not working properly.

[image]

```
  HashMap<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<>();
                        datamap.put("category", selected_item);
                        datamap.put("group_name", group_name);
                        datamap.put("group_link", group_link);
                        datamap.put("group_type", group_type);
                        datamap.put("language", language);
                        datamap.put("report_status", count);
                        String date=ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toString();
                        datamap.put("time", date);
```

i added data like this and also date is not showing. please help me to add date and sort the data.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting: I'm not entirely sure if this is feasible for you, but you could possible try to set the timestamp in place of the key. Perhaps this might order it by the time? Don't quote me on that.

For the date bug: Instead of using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toString();` just use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code .

```
HashMap<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<>();
                    datamap.put("category", selected_item);
                    datamap.put("group_name", group_name);
                    datamap.put("group_link", group_link);
                    datamap.put("group_type", group_type);
                    datamap.put("language", language);
                    datamap.put("report_status", count);
                    datamap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

or
you can push jSon as follows.

```
 var sessionsRef = firebase.database().ref("sessions");
sessionsRef.push({
  startedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```